# Future timestamp fields are interpreting strangely while loading into snowflake stage

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While loading a parquet file into snowflake table, a timestamp column with value **'4162-12-31 00:00:00.000'** is getting converted into **'1790-03-24 02:07:11.452'**. Other futuristic timestamps like '2032-12-31 00:00:00.000' are getting interpreted fine. The file is generated through Spark and are being sent to AWS S3 for snowflake to consume. When the file is put in the external stage, the variant values are showing changed there itself, even before loading into the table.

Tried with other timestamps, they are all working as expected, except for the above particular value.

Is this a known bug? How can I overcome this?

Comment: "When the file is put in the external stage, the variant values are showing changed there itself" - How the file is being loaded to stage, any conversion used there and how the value is being checked post upload to stage? At snowflake if we just do a simple select with this timestamp there is no conversion - e.g. select to_timestamp('4162-12-31 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

Answer (score 1):

Lets dig into this:

```
select '4162-12-31 00:00:00.000' as far_date_str
    ,'1790-03-24 02:07:11.452' as past_date_str
    ,'2032-12-31 00:00:00.000' as near_date_str
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(far_date_str) as far_date
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(past_date_str) as past_date
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(near_date_str) as near_date
```

| FAR_DATE_STR | PAST_DATE_STR | NEAR_DATE_STR | FAR_DATE | PAST_DATE | NEAR_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4162-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 1790-03-24 02:07:11.452 | 2032-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 4162-12-31 00:00:00.000 | 1790-03-24 02:07:12.548 | 2032-12-31 00:00:00.000 |

So snowflake can handle these date ranges fine. (the "far_date_str" is the one of primary interest..)

so lets look how those values are represented in decimal and hex:

```
select 
    to_timestamp_ntz('4162-12-31 00:00:00.000') as far_date
    ,date_part(epoch_seconds, far_date) as fd_epoch_s
    ,to_char(fd_epoch_s, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hfd_epoch_s

    ,to_timestamp_ntz('1790-03-24 02:07:11.452') as past_date
    ,date_part(epoch_seconds, past_date) as pd_epoch_s
    ,to_char(pd_epoch_s, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hpd_epoch_s
```

| column | value |
| --- | --- |
| FAR_DATE | 4162-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| FD_EPOCH_S | 69,204,326,400 |
| HFD_EPOCH_S | 101ce63800 |
| PAST_DATE | 1790-03-24 02:07:12.548 |
| PD_EPOCH_S | -5,673,102,769 |
| HPD_EPOCH_S | fffffffeaddb524f |

here we see that the "truncated far future date" is a negative time (in epoch space)    which is making me wonder, at some point is that "future" number too large for some system thus the value was truncated, it's new value has top bit set, and become a negative number.

Lets look at milliseconds and nanosecond representation.

```
select 
    to_timestamp_ntz('4162-12-31 00:00:00.000') as far_date

    ,to_timestamp_ntz('1790-03-24 02:07:11.452') as past_date

    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_milliseconds, far_date), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hfd_epoch_ms

    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_milliseconds, past_date), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hpd_epoch_ms

    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_microseconds, far_date), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hfd_epoch_us
    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_microseconds, past_date), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hpd_epoch_us
    
    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_nanoseconds, far_date),  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hfd_epoch_ns
    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_nanoseconds, past_date), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hpd_epoch_ns
```

| column | value |
| --- | --- |
| FAR_DATE | 4162-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| PAST_DATE | 1790-03-24 02:07:12.548 |
| HFD_EPOCH_MS | 3ef0e34ac000 |
| HPD_EPOCH_MS | fffffad720b9865c |
| HFD_EPOCH_US | f5dcf7dbfe0000 |
| HPD_EPOCH_US | ffebd857d4b4d760 |
| HFD_EPOCH_NS | 3c067283358300000 |
| HPD_EPOCH_NS | ffb1451716e2694f00 |

so if we look at those nanosecond epochs, that require more value space than an unsigned int 64 can hold, and the future number leading nibbles `c0` is rather close to the leading nibbles of the "truncated number" `b1`

```
 3,c0672833,58300000 
ff,b1451716,e2694f00
```

```
select 
    to_timestamp_ntz('4162-12-31 00:00:00.000') as far_date

    ,to_timestamp_ntz('1790-03-24 02:07:11.452') as past_date
    
    ,to_char(date_part(epoch_nanoseconds, far_date),  'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as hfd_epoch_ns
    ,-to_number(right(hfd_epoch_ns, 16), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') as trunc_ns
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(trunc_ns,9) as trunc_date
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(0,9) as zero_date
    ,datediff('year', past_date, trunc_date)
;
```

| column | value |
| --- | --- |
| FAR_DATE | 4162-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
| PAST_DATE | 1790-03-24 02:07:12.548 |
| HFD_EPOCH_NS | 3c067283358300000 |
| TRUNC_NS | -13,864,094,178,871,345,152 |
| TRUNC_DATE | 1530-08-31 22:43:42.871 |
| ZERO_DATE | 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| DATEDIFF('YEAR') | -260 |

So we have 260 year between our dates, and Snowflake "zero" date is 1970 which is 130 years less than the year 2000. So if there is a system that bases dates as nano seconds since 2000-01-01 and only uses 64bit to represent these values. That would make what we see here happen.

If we go look at the Hive documentation for [Timestamps](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp) we see it uses nanoseconds, and only support up range `1677-09-21T00:12:43.15` and `2262-04-11T23:47:16.8`. So if your values went through Hive, that would have ruined your data.

You mention Spark, and all I can find is Spark (since 2014) uses INT96 to store timestamp, thus I assume the is not the source of your problem.

I would be inclined to make a time parquet file with a couple of wildly time datetimes in them, check to can write then to a file, and then read them in your tool. If that is all happy, then see if snowflake can load these, which would imply Snowflake is the problem. But if snowflake is happy, it implies what ever wrote you files, or something earlier in your data pipeline is doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks @simeon for the explanation. The file is generated with PySpark and it is defining the schema as its default data type, timestamp in particular. When changed the datatype in the python code to varchar, snowflake is able to properly parse it. Checking the file in snowflake external stage (S3), I can see the parquet file contains proper data, which means the loading into the stage location is fine. But, when I try to read it in snowflake from the stage directly, it is changing the timestamp data. Records in parquet being in JSON, not sure how SF is manipulating the data inside a variant.

Comment: hmm, JSON code is auto-magic parsed and stored as "it's type" to boost things. So if that code had representation limits, that might trigger this behavior..  sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Thanks @simeon for the insight on how timestamps are being calculated at epoch level. It was indeed an issue in generating the parquet file. Added a small line for Spark to use before writing data to the file. `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType","TIMESTAMP_MICROS")`. This fixed the issue and whichever timestamp I am using in parquet is being perfectly parsed and read in snowflake.

Comment: lovely, nanoseconds and the year 4000 are somewhat in different ballparks of needs. Nice solution